# Showing that given a graph $G$, does it exists a clique in $G$ of length $\ge k$" for a given $k\in\mathbb{N}$ is NP-complete

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np

> Let be the following problem : "Given a graph $G$, does it exists a clique in $G$ of length $\ge k$" for a given $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Show that it is NP-Complete

I know how to show that

- a set of vertices $S$ is a stable set in $G$ iif $S$ is a clique in
  $G_C$.
- the Hamiltonian cycle problem is in $NP$

And I know the definition of NP complete problems.

**Do you have any tips to show that this problem is NP-Complete?**

#### My attempt

I count how much $G_C$ is a stable, at most $n$ operations, I store the best value, for instance $4$. Therefore, it will give a clique of length $n-4$. But I show there that we can search for a solution in a polynomial time. Not that we can verify the solution in polynomial time. Thus, I show that it is $P$, not in $NP$...

Comment: Basically, you need to build a polynomial-time reduction from another NP-complete problem (like say 3-SAT). I think it would be a good idea for you to look at some example reductions to get the feel for how such reductions are constructed.

Answer (score 0):

It is a classical example of reduction the Hamiltonian cycle to vertex cover. Also, if $S \subset V$ is a vertex cover then $V \setminus S$ is an independent (stable) set. Thus, taking the graph complement you obtain a clique.

According to your attempt, firstly how can you find stable set in $G_c$ in $n$ steps? Secondly, review what is a complement graph.